# FBSDKShare not work in ios 9

Tags: facebook, share, ios9, slcomposeviewcontroller

I use FBSDKShare to share image to Facebook.The code work well in iOS 8, but not iOS 9.Recently I use Xcode Version 7.0 (7A220) to recompile my code.I know there has some difference between iOS version.I have read the Facebook [document](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/ios9) and did everything as in the document. I used the last Facebook SDK v4.6 and also use pod to manager the FBSDKShare.

Thanks to the pods, I can debug into FBSDKShareKit code. I found in FBSDKShareKit->FBSDKShareDialog.m line 546,the SLComposeViewController cannot create in iOS 9.The code is like:

```
SLComposeViewController *composeViewController = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];
```

Not same code but same result.The composeViewController is nil, I have no issue why this happen.

Comment: This sounds like a possible bug. I would file one on developers.facebook.com/bugs, and include a github repo with a minimal sample application which reproduces this error consistently.